# How can I loop over columns in R in a dataset to create cross tabs for each column and a grouping factor, and then apply a fisher's exact test?

Tags: r, function, loops, statistics, crosstab

I have a dataset with ~100 columns and ~1000 rows. For each column except that last, I would like to create a cross tab of the values and a grouping factor, which is the last column in the dataset. I would then like to perform a Fisher's Exact test on each of the cross tabs.

I have this all working in a hardcoded format, but am looking to use a loop or function to clean up and optimize the code

Comment: Please read [ask]! Give a [mcve], i.e. edit your question. It seems to me you are looking for the function `aggregate()` or similar.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `lapply()` to loop over your 99 columns and create a list of 99 contingency tables. Afterwards, use `lapply()` again to loop over your list of tables and create a table of 99 results of `fisher.test()`.

```
mytables <- lapply(df[, 1:99], function(x) table(x, df[, 100]))

mytests <- lapply(mytables, fisher.test)
```